# postgresql optimize query analyze explain

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, explain

Hi all postgresql experts. I am maintaining a web application I did neither conceive or develop, and there is a query that takes 5 minutes (yes minutes) to complete. As I am not familiar at all with PostgreSQL I have ran the "explain analyze" and here is the query and the output of the explain analyze. I would be very grateful if someone could explain ( :-) ) to me how to improve the query or just give me some pointers to understand the output :)

### here is the query :

```
explain analyse SELECT a.salon as salonid, a.salon_ratachement,
 (CASE WHEN a.salon IS NOT NULL THEN (select debut FROM salon WHERE id = a.salon) ELSE
 a.hors_salon_date_debut END) as debut,
 (CASE WHEN a.salon IS NOT NULL THEN (select fin FROM salon WHERE id = a.salon) ELSE a
.hors_salon_date_fin END) as fin,
 (CASE WHEN a.salon IS NOT NULL THEN (select nom_fra FROM salon WHERE id = a.salon) WHEN a.salon_ratachement IS NOT NULL THEN (select nom_fra FROM salon WHERE id = a.salon_ratachement)||' (hors salon)' ELSE 'Hors salon' END ) as nom_salon,
 a.id, a.reference, a.numero, ad.numero as numero_additif, a.jour_installation_souhaite,
 ad.id as additifid, ad.statut_logistique, ad.etat, e.id as espaceid, e.code, e.nom,
c.id as clientid, c.nom as nom_client, c.lang
 FROM client c, espace e, additif ad , affaire a, salon s

 WHERE  true  and a.salon = '1237' and s.id = 1237
 AND (ad.etat='NON CONFIRME' OR ad.etat='CONFIRME')  and a.est_archive = 'false' AND (
ad.statut_logistique='a_preparer' OR ad.statut_logistique='en_preparation' OR ad.statut_logistique='a_installer' OR ad.statut_logistique='installe_partiellement' OR ad.statut_logistique='installe' OR ad.statut_logistique='desinstalle_partiellement' OR ad.statut_logistique='desinstalle')  AND e.affaire=a.id AND a.client=c.id AND ad.affaire=a.id AND ad.espace=e.id
 AND ((ad.id in (select lc.additif from ligne_commande lc, prestation p where lc.additif=ad .id and lc.prestation=p.id ))  OR (ad.statut_logistique_force='t')) ORDER BY  (case when a.salon is not null then a.salon::varchar||'b' when a.salon_ratachement is not null then a.salon_ratachement::varchar||'a' else '0' end) desc, a.id desc, ad.id;
```

### and here is the explain output :

QUERY PLAN

```
Sort  (cost=16051791.56..16051791.57 rows=1 width=143) (actual time=281189.406..281189.406 rows=5 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (a.salon IS NOT NULL) THEN (((a.salon)::character varying)::text || 'b'::text) WHEN (a.salon_ratachement IS NOT NULL) THEN (((a.salon_ratachement)::character varying)::text || 'a'::text) ELSE '0'::text END), a.id, ad.id
  Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 26kB
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=889.24..16051791.55 rows=1 width=143) (actual time=56077.822..281189.319 rows=5 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (a.id = e.affaire)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=889.24..16051757.76 rows=2 width=112) (actual time=56077.716..281188.945 rows=5 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (a.id = ad.affaire)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..961.46 rows=1 width=77) (actual time=0.096..8.279 rows=5 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..953.19 rows=1 width=77) (actual time=0.084..8.225 rows=5 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using affaire_pkey on affaire a  (cost=0.00..944.91 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=0.065..8.121 rows=5 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((NOT est_archive) AND (salon = 1237))
                          ->  Index Scan using client_pkey on client c  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=5)
                                Index Cond: (c.id = a.client)
                    ->  Index Scan using salon_pkey on salon s  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=1 loops=5)
                          Index Cond: (s.id = 1237)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on additif ad  (cost=889.24..16050626.95 rows=13548 width=35) (actual time=4.506..56229.985 rows=17173 loops=5)
                    Recheck Cond: ((((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'a_preparer'::text) OR ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'en_preparation'::text) OR ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'a_installer'::text) OR ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'installe_partiellement'::text) OR ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'installe'::text) OR ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'desinstalle_partiellement'::text) OR ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'desinstalle'::text)) AND (((ad.etat)::text = 'NON CONFIRME'::text) OR ((ad.etat)::text = 'CONFIRME'::text)))
                    Filter: ((SubPlan 5) OR ad.statut_logistique_force)
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=889.24..889.24 rows=17129 width=0) (actual time=4.173..4.173 rows=0 loops=5)
                          ->  BitmapOr  (cost=443.27..443.27 rows=17304 width=0) (actual time=2.013..2.013 rows=0 loops=5)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statut_logistique_key  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=27 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=51 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'a_preparer'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statut_logistique_key  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=27 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=4 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'en_preparation'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statut_logistique_key  (cost=0.00..46.17 rows=1856 width=0) (actual time=0.245..0.245 rows=1783 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'a_installer'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statut_logistique_key  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=27 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'installe_partiellement'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statut_logistique_key  (cost=0.00..23.84 rows=1012 width=0) (actual time=0.118..0.118 rows=985 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'installe'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statut_logistique_key  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=27 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=49 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'desinstalle_partiellement'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statut_logistique_key  (cost=0.00..331.73 rows=14330 width=0) (actual time=1.594..1.594 rows=14329 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.statut_logistique)::text = 'desinstalle'::text)
                          ->  BitmapOr  (cost=445.71..445.71 rows=18458 width=0) (actual time=2.116..2.116 rows=0 loops=5)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on etat_key  (cost=0.00..4.27 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=2 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.etat)::text = 'NON CONFIRME'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on etat_key  (cost=0.00..434.67 rows=18456 width=0) (actual time=2.105..2.105 rows=18409 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: ((ad.etat)::text = 'CONFIRME'::text)
                    SubPlan 5
                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1873.85 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=3.271..3.271 rows=1 loops=85885)
                            ->  Seq Scan on ligne_commande lc  (cost=0.00..1849.01 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=3.264..3.264 rows=1 loops=85885)
                                  Filter: (additif = $4)
                            ->  Index Scan using prestation_pkey on prestation p  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=85790)
                                  Index Cond: (p.id = lc.prestation)
        ->  Index Scan using espace_pkey on espace e  (cost=0.00..0.34 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=1 loops=5)
              Index Cond: (e.id = ad.espace)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Index Scan using salon_pkey on salon  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=1 loops=5)
                Index Cond: (id = $0)
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Index Scan using salon_pkey on salon  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=5)
                Index Cond: (id = $1)
        SubPlan 3
          ->  Index Scan using salon_pkey on salon  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=5)
                Index Cond: (id = $2)
        SubPlan 4
          ->  Index Scan using salon_pkey on salon  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=14) (never executed)
                Index Cond: (id = $3)
Total runtime: 281189.828 ms
```

---

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Maybe an index on ligne_command columns that are used in the joins?

Comment: What iabou this `WHERE true and...` in the query? Does not truly look intentional.

Comment: You might also try converting the `OR`s into `UNION`s. It is much more query text. But with large amounts of data it could have drastic performance effects (at least upto and including 9.4 versions)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it's postgresql 8.4 server :-o

Comment: And I seem to not recognize a condition joining back `salon s` to the other tables. Is this by intention?

Comment: @rpy JOIN syntax would have prevented this. To me it looks like this whole CASE(salon) stuff could be replaced by a LEFT JOIN+COALESCE() on the salon table.

Comment: Thank you Fabrizio (the "Seq Scan on ligne_commande lc  (cost=0.00..1849.01 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=3.264..3.264 rows=1 loops=85885)" was the key :)